# Raspbian Jessie: startup script doesn't work

Tags: boot, raspberry-pi, systemd, autostart

I'm running Raspbian Jessie Lite on RPi3. I created a file in `/etc/systemd/system/autostart.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Application

[Service]
User=root
ExecStart=/home/pi/autostart.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The service is correctly enabled and actually executed.
Here the source of my startup script:

```
#!/bin/sh
aplay -c2 -r48000 -fS16_LE < /dev/zero &
chmod 1777 /tmp
hciconfig hci0 up
/home/pi/bin/./app
```

My app is executed but has weird behaviors, while running it from a root console as `/home/pi/bin/./app` leads to no issue.
Furthermore, of course, the `autostart.sh` script remains in execution until my application ends.

To fix both problems I tried to run it in background, adding `&` at the end. Or just tried to redirect the output to a file adding `&> /home/pi/log.txt`. In both cases my application is not executed anymore!

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing these things:

1. Add `Type=oneshot` to the [Service] section. No need to background it, and redirecting the output to a file won't work any in the config file anyway. Output is already captured and redirected using the `StandardOutput` key, which defaults to sending it to the systemd journal.
2. Also, simply creating the file doesn't make executed, you also have to enable it.  Run

   ```
   systemctl enable autostart
   ```

I'll also note that you end up running `/home/pi/bin/app` as root, which may not be what you want for security. Unless there's a need to run it as root, consider running your app as another user.

Comment: I edited my question, the service is already enabled. I will try the `oneshot` settings. After further digging I ended up the issues are due to some env vars not set when my application runs. I exported them from `/etc/profile`, Perhaps they are not read (yet?) from systemd.

Comment: To provide the environment variables to systemd, use as either the [`Environment=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Environment=) o  [`PassEnvironment=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#PassEnvironment=) directives as directed in the documentation.